# Is there any way to reduce the spaces between UV islands without scaling the actual islands?

Tags: uv, scale

I know about Ctrl+P, I know about Individual Origins scaling, that is not what I am looking for, I am looking for the scale tool that reduces empty space between a selection of scatered, non-uniform UV islands without actually scaling said islands. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> move your cursor or let your cursor be in 3D window and press <kbd>F6</kbd>. A popup will appear - play with the settings there to adjust how much spacing you need.

[image]

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. The operation you suggested, translates all the islands randomly and fills the entire UV quad with them. What I need is the ability to reduce the spaces between only a few selected islands out of the entire set, without changing (drastically) their positions.